# Splitting a timestamp record

Tags: php, mysql

I got a timestamp record in my msql db which has date and time.
I would to get just the time from it, or just time hour and minute.

How can I split that record?

**EDIT** here is a picture of my table:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function:

```sql
SELECT TIME(my_column) FROM my_table
```

To obtain only the date part, you can use the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

Comment: I use it but I get nothing: SELECT location,TIME('time') FROM locations WHERE id='5' ORDER BY time ASC

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Why are you quoting your column name as a string literal, whereas I am not?  If you want to quote SQL identifiers, you should use backtick, not apostrophe `'`.

Comment: You need to change TIME('time') to TIME(\`time\`) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Ok I just did and I get the same result, nothing. Is there anything wrong in my query?

Comment: If you're getting no results at all, not even an error, the most likely explanation is that you don't have a record with `id='5'`.

Comment: My table is full of records and it's working fine if I just select my time column normally but I guess you gave me the right answer I just do something wrong. if you see something wrong please let me know.thanks.

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Are you saying that ``SELECT location, TIME(`time`) FROM locations WHERE id='5' ORDER BY time ASC`` gives no results, but ``SELECT location, `time` FROM locations WHERE id='5' ORDER BY time ASC`` does give results?

Comment: Yes just tested. but I type time not 'time', you can see it here: http://imrip.interhost.co.il/ right column is the location and the left is the time.

Comment: @ImriPersiado: Those "times" don't look like MySQL timestamps to me (they're not in ISO format).  You *really* should convert the column to one of MySQL's temporal types, such as [`TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) (the difference boils down to the former respecting timezones and the latter ignoring them).  You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to help perform such conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) or [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get a specific format e.g. only hh:mm

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%H:%i' );
+-------------------------------------------+
| TIME_FORMAT( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%H:%i' ) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 17:25                                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT**

The function of course works for columns of a table as well

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( myColumn, '%H:%i' ) FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Why to use curent timestamp?I have the time in the db already I just want to show him diffrently

Comment: It gives me nothing how come: SELECT location,TIME_FORMAT( time, '%H:%i' ) FROM locations ORDER BY time ASC

Comment: If this returns nothing in terms of 0 rows you simply have an empty table or your where clause is too restrictive, add the table structure  (`SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable`) and sample data to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Also can try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%r') AS timestamp;

|   TIMESTAMP |
---------------
| 03:51:43 PM |

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_Datetimecolumn,'%r') AS timestamp;
```

Comment: Why do you use the now method?I have a time in the db I don't want to create another time.

Comment: You can have your column :D it's just a sample here.

Comment: Please leave a comment for downvote :) @ImriPersiado if you have downvoted please see my comment above. I only used `Now()` to give you a sample output. And plese know that OP has mentioned either time or hour and minute, so my answer doesn't have a flaw :(